# Error is showing on else if and && statement

Tags: syntax-error

```
if(u<=100)
charge=u*1.35;
else if(u=>100&&u<=200)
```

What's wrong with this last statement? It is showing an error.

Comment: Which programming language? What error does it show? Please edit your question such that it answers these questions. (Add a tag for the programming language, and append the error message(s) to your question.) Thank you!

Comment: @stakx: User last seen... "May 1st, 2011." I don't think he's coming back... =)

Comment: @David: I think it's still worth pointing out what is wrong with a question (e.g. in the case where another new user stumbles over this question; they should see what is expected of a question on SO).

Answer (score 4):

would help if you mentioned what language this is for but probably you should be using `>=` instead of `=>`

Answer (score 2):

`if (u <= 100) charge = u * 1.35; else if (u >= 100 && u <= 200)`

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(u=>100&&u<=200)
         ^^-- here
```

shouldn't the indicated portion be `>=`? As well, if that's the entirety of the code, you're missing something for this `else if` to act on...

```
if (...) {
   ...
else if (...) {
   you're missing this part here
}
```